# Can anyone explain this R language ts function

Tags: r, time-series

```
myts <- ts(mydata[,2:4], start = c(1981, 1), frequency = 4)
```

Above line of code is clear to me except the part ts(mydata[,2:4]) I know that ts(mydata[,2] tells us that R should read from 2 column however, what does 2:4 stands for?
data looks like this

```
usnim
1   2002-01-01  4.08
2   2002-04-01  4.10
3   2002-07-01  4.06
4   2002-10-01  4.04
```

Could you provide an example when to use 2:4 ?

Comment: That notation selects columns 2, 3, and 4, from `mydata`.  It doesn't have anything to do with `ts()`, per se.  `ts` accepts "a vector or matrix of the observed time-series values. A data frame will be coerced to a numeric matrix via data.matrix" in the `data` argument, so this should not be an issue.  see `?ts`

Comment: Thanks, andrew_reece